# Will my Shared Self-Hosted Integration Runtime be available to other Azure Data Factories during a regional Azure outage?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have 3 Azure Data Factories.

- **DF_Shared_IR**:

  - Empty, save for a Shared Self-Hosted Integration Runtime (on-premise, 2 nodes).
  - Deployed in region 1 (Australia East).
- **DF_1**:

  - Has pipelines which perform hourly data loads and other ETL jobs.
  - Has a Linked Integration Runtime (referencing the IR hosted within **DF_Shared_IR**).
  - Deployed in region 1 (Australia East).
- **DF_2**:

  - Is a replica of **DF_1**.
  - Deployed in region 2 (Australia Southeast).

In the unlikely event of a regional outage in region 1 (in which **DF_1** and **DF_Shared_IR** are impacted), I want to enable all triggers within **DF_2** and resume normal hourly data loads.

I have reviewed the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#high-availability-and-scalability). It is clear to me that I can make my Shared Self Hosted Integration Runtime highly-available by adding multiple nodes - however it is unclear whether the Azure components which enable communication to the on-premise Integration Runtime are also highly available.

Will the Shared Self-Hosted Integration Runtime (hosted within **DF_Shared_IR**) be available to **DF_2** in this disaster recovery scenario? If not how can I support this scenario, and ensure service continuity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes.

After opening a ticket with Azure regarding this question, Microsoft Support advised the data movement service within Data Factory which enables connectivity to the on-premise Integration Runtime is considered highly available.

Within Data Factory, you can review the Service URLs in your self-hosted IR settings.

- Click **View Service URLs**.
  [image]
  [image]
- Observe the service URLs with the domain name *.servicebus.windows.net which are required by the self-hosted integration runtime to connect to data movement services in Azure Data Factory.

[image]

The listed URLs represent services from two regions (sg3 and hk2). One is default and the other provides high availability. This design ensures connectivity remains available between your self-hosted IR and data movement service in Data Factory while either of the regions meet outage.